Angular: Primeng InputNumber, Calendar styling errors in Google Chrome
In an Angular project, using primeng form input, specificity in chrome browser, I am getting this weird black circle inside primeng number inputs.
<p-inputNumber
          mode="decimal"
          [min]="0"
          [minFractionDigits]="2"
          [maxFractionDigits]="2"
          id="rentPerAnnum"
          inputId="minmaxfraction"
          formControlName="parkingPrice"
          (onBlur)="
            formatToDouble(leaseDetailsGroup, 'parkingPrice')
          "
          class="w-8"
        />


and A white circle in this element which is not in the background.

and in table:

Empty date fields for the calendar.
 <p-calendar
          [readonlyInput]="false"
          [dateFormat]="'dd-mm-yy'"
          formControlName="registeredDate"
          id="registeredDate"
          inputId="registeredDate"
          [iconDisplay]="'input'"
          [showIcon]="true"
          placeholder="Select"
          styleClass="w-full"
          (onSelect)="onDateSelect($event, 'registeredDate')"
        ></p-calendar>


I checked on other browsers like Firefox and ran the code on other laptops, it works just fine,
I am open to any suggestions.
Google chrome: Version 130.0.6723.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS

Please post a minimal reproduction of the problem on Stackblitz

@ihebkhodja right click that circle, then select inspect, then find the origin of the circle, you might need to set z-index for the circle with value as 1, so that it does not overlay the primeng elements

@NarenMurali The circle element cant be selected, it just shows up as background color
